# Should the context attributes in web application being made thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a context (e.g. TestContext.java) as a singleton in the web application.
Multi struts actions will access the context. Should I create the context attributes as thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should: several theads may access it simultaneously.